# I don't have a "./bin/www" file

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, npm, bin

To start things off, please know that I'm incredibly new to the whole web development world, so if I say anything that doesn't make sense, please let me know. So I've been following some guide on how to develop a simple restful app, but I hit a wall when I tried using 'npm start' to set up (the first version of) the restful app. The error says that it can't locate "./bin/www" - which is fair enough, www (whatever that is) doesn't exist, and neither does the bin directory. I've set up the 'skeleton' using the express command, and I've done minor modifications but they have all been according to this tutorial, and I haven't  touched the placed in the json file where it states the starting directory (and neither has the person in the tutorial). Any help would be incredibly appreciated.

```
omar@omar-S550CM:~/Desktop/Projects/WebPages/nodetest2$ ls -a
.  ..  app.js  data  node_modules  package.json  public  routes  views
omar@omar-S550CM:~/Desktop/Projects/WebPages/nodetest2$ npm start

> nodetest2b@0.0.0 start /home/omar/Desktop/Projects/WebPages/nodetest2
> node ./bin/www


module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/omar/Desktop/Projects/WebPages/nodetest2/bin/www'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Note: npm and nodejs seem to be working fine otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh....after looking into it for quite a bit, it seemed like my whole nodejs environment might be a bit botched; and it certainly was. I uninstalled all nodejs elements and re-installed everything using nvm (via this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-express-a-node-js-framework-and-set-up-socket-io-on-a-vps), and it works perfectly now.